# Center an image in an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center an image in an anchor tag to act as a search button. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tempjBuk/ndb4cqpa/3/) is a link the Fiddle.

there have been other questions like this, but they do not answer my question.

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
    $('.fixme').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0',
      left: '0'
    });
  } else {
    $('.fixme').css({
      position: 'static'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.search {
  float: right;
}

#form1 input {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
  float: left;
}

#form1 a {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 0 0 -32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.fixme {
  float: right;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="search">
      <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
        <a class="a" href="#"><img src="img/search-icon.png" height="42" width="42" /></a>
      </form>

    </div>

    <div class="button-login">

    </div>

    <div class="fixme">sticky</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

This is what is happening:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h5TL.png)

I have tried everything, but I cannot figure out how to center my image...

Is there an easy way around this with css?

Thank you, Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Upload the image to e.g. imgur.com and reference it in your code, so we can actually see your issue. Also, why is your search *button* an anchor, not an actual `button`?

Comment: what other Stack Overflow questions did you look at and why specifically did they not work for you?

Comment: all the other questions had question-specific answers. I need an answer specific to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the center tag, wrap the elments you want to center with this tag:

```
   <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <center>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
        <a class="a" href="#"><img src="img/search-icon.png" height="42" width="42" /></a>
        </center>
   </form>
```

You can also wray your elements with a div and do the style there:

```
    <div style="text-align:center;" >
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
    <a class="a" href="#"><img src="img/search-icon.png" height="42" width="42" /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `center` tag is obsolete and has been deprecated and therefore is strongly advised against being used in new projects. It's browser support could be removed at any time. The alternative is to use `text-align` CSS on a `div` or `p` element.

More detail can be read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

The a tag is not a css block, but rather an inline element. You would have to make the a tag a block with css display: inline-block. Then you can use text-align: center.